# One for All, and All for One

Tags: riddle

We three are one
For ear or tongue
Yet not for eye nor hand
Of our good three
But one lacks three
As this riddle lacks we

Answer (score 28, accepted):

These are

> the words `to`, `two` and `too`.

We three are one
For ear or tongue
Yet not for eye nor hand

> They sound the same, but are written differently.

Of our good three
But one lacks three

> Only one of the words has fewer than three letters, the others have exactly three.

As this riddle lacks we

> None of these words appear in the riddle.

Note that

> There are other possibilities, eg. `so`, `sew` and `sow`, but given the references to one and three, `two` seems the most natural answer.